# How to display image and text within same Object property with JSON and vue.js

Tags: json, vue.js

It has been a while since i have been able to work in vue. I am trying to bring in my text and image together in the same "content" property, but it isn't resolving the file path when I am testing this on my local server. I am using v-html on my div, which brings in the text, but a broken image tag with the error cannot GET file path is shown.

my object:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "category": "Headline",
    "info": {
      "headline": "Secondary Header",
      "content": "<p>this is text</p><img class='content-img' src='./assets/my-image.jpg' /><p>This is more text</p>"
    }
  }
```

my html:

```
<template>
  <div class="help-content">
     <h1>{{this.helpList[myIndex].category}}</h1>
     <div v-html="this.helpList[this.myIndex].info.content"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'HelpContent',
  props: ['loadedCategory', 'myIndex'],
  computed: {
    helpList () {
      return this.$store.state.helpList
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">
</style>
```

from my understanding I thought i didn't need to write additional code in order for it to resolve this? I must not be searching with the right keywords because i cannot find threads where this is shown.
There will be multiple objects and all will have varying text and images in the content object, which is why i can't separate the image into it's own object

Answer (score 0):

Chose to add my images to the public folder and use an absolute path